# SSRS: Using lookupset to get multiple fields

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets:

My main dataset (Students) looks like this:

```
Student Name      | PID
Anakin SkyWalker  | 1
Obi-Wan Kenobi    | 2
```

And my second dataset (Awards) looks like this:

```
PID  | Xtrnl_Award_Type | Xtrnl_Award_Date
1    | BS               | 200912
2    | BA               | 200605
2    | MS               | 200905
```

What I want to get is this:

```
Student Name      | Awards
Anakin SkyWalker  | BS - 200912
Obi-Wan Kenobi    | BA - 200605, MS - 200905
```

The LookupSet function can only return one field in the second dataset.  Is there some other way I can get the results I want?  The second dataset is on another server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an expression as the target Dataset field:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!PID.Value
    , Fields!PID.Value
    , Fields!Xtrnl_Award_Type.Value & " - " & Fields!Xtrnl_Award_Date.Value
    , "Awards"), ", ")
```

Works for me based on your data:

[image]

Comment: That would work, I forgot about the & connector.  I'll give it a try.  That worked better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I can get what I wanted by adding a calculated field to my second data set that combined the two fields.

Comment: Of course, that added some time to the query, so that was not the best solution in this case.